# MySQL get a column's created / modified from information schema?

Tags: php, mysql, information-schema

Is there a way to know when a column has been created / modified from information_schema database?

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. There are fields in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES for the datetime of table creation and update, but even this is not tracked reliably for InnoDB.